# No input for email in my tempate

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, input

I have a form where I must enter e-mail, but in the template do not have space for input, only after passing the validation window appears with the introduction e-mail.
At this moment I see only send button.

This is my code:

```
          <div class="col-lg-6">
              <form action="./" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                  <input type="submit" value="send">
              </form>
          </div>
```

model.py

```
class InputEmail(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

forms.py

```
from models import InputEmail
from django import forms


class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = InputEmail
        fields = ('email',)
```

views.py

```
class Home(View):

    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = EmailForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, "You send e-mail to us!")
                return HttpResponseRedirect('./')
        else:
            form = EmailForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {
            'form': form
        })
```

The rest - writing and reading from the database works fine.

How enter the input and give it a style?

Comment: Can you please share your views/model/form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well the problem is that the first time you arrive to the view the `get` method is being called (and it is okay, since this is a GET request).
But, inside that `get` method you are not sending your form to the template. So it can't be rendered.

instead, your `get` method should look like that:

```
def get(self, request):
    form = EmailForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```

note that the condition in the `post` method is redundant. You have an "else" but you never get there since the `post` method is only called when it is a POST request.
Meaning your `post` method should look like this:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = EmailForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('./')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {
        'form': form
    })
```